# How to connect to office365 using IMAPS protocol from Java application

Tags: java, office365, office365api

There are few articles out there about this, but non of them worked for me. Basically I have following java code to connect to office 365:

```
  Properties props = new Properties();
  props.put("mail.imaps.auth.plain.disable", "true");
  props.put("mail.imaps.ssl.enable", "true");

  session = Session.getInstance(props, null);
  store = session.getStore("imaps");
  store.connect("outlook.office365.com", 993, "user@mydomain.com", "psw");
```

but it fails with LOGIN failed error;

```
javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: LOGIN failed.
        at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:725)
        at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:366)
```

Also I'm able to login into my account using IMAPS from Thunderbird.

Any pointers to resolve an issue would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me for outlook I have modified it for use with Office365. I did the research to find the IMAP host for office 365. I hope it helps you.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws MessagingException {
    MultiPartEmail email = new MultiPartEmail();
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");

    //extra codes required for reading OUTLOOK mails during IMAP-start
    props.setProperty("mail.imaps.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    props.setProperty("mail.imaps.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
    props.setProperty("mail.imaps.port", "993");
    props.setProperty("mail.imaps.socketFactory.port", "993");
    //extra codes required for reading OUTLOOK mails during IMAP-end

    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
    Store store = session.getStore("imaps");
    store.connect("outlook.office365.com", "some.one@some.org", "mypassword");
    Folder inbox = store.getFolder("INBOX");
    inbox.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);


    inbox.addMessageCountListener(new MessageCountListener() {
        @Override
        public void messagesAdded(MessageCountEvent messageCountEvent) {
            Message[] messages = messageCountEvent.getMessages();
            System.out.println("A message was added, you now have: " + messages.length + " emails");
        }

        @Override
        public void messagesRemoved(MessageCountEvent messageCountEvent) {

        }

    });

    while (true) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1500);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        inbox.getMessageCount(); // Keeps connection alive
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for an answer, but this didn't help. Connections are refused with same LOGIN failed exception. Also made sure IMAPS access protocol is enabled on our office 365 server.

Answer (score 0):

As it turned out, office 365 was rejecting connections because of unsupported characters inside the password. Particularly quote character. So, as simple as changing psw fixed my problem.

And following code snippet works just fine:

```
  Properties props = new Properties();
  props.put("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");

  session = Session.getInstance(props, null);
  store = session.getStore();
  store.connect("outlook.office365.com", 993, "user@mydomain.com", "psw");
```

With 'javax.mail', version: '1.5.6'